# How does onboarding custom account by yourself work on stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I am developing a platform which allows multiple customers to directly pay to service providers. I am using stripe connect for it.

I'm having trouble understanding how to onboard the service provider to my platform. I want to do all that manually, like collecting their info and feeding it while creating custom account. But I'm having problem figuring out how's it going to work. Right now I have created an an API in development mode, and it does create a user account. But it says payout disabled and disabled_reason is 'requirements.pending_verification'

So how will stripe verify it on it's own? And how much time will it take for them to verify. Also, I'm not attaching any documents like ID to the data, so how are they going to verify it?

I have tried creating different APIs with different parameters. But I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass Stripe Account verification in test mode you need to use special string in some fields. You can read more about this topic [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#identity-and-address-verification).

Comment: How will the Stripe Account Verification work in Real(non test) mode?